# Detect root folder with php

Tags: php, file, php-include

hello there i need help with this.
i have two files css1.php and css2.php if the user is on the root folder of the domain i need to include css1.php and if users are inside another like /incomes i need to inlcude css2.php.
i want to do this because i am using only 1 header for all the site and the header has to include the css file.

right now i have this

```
$svr = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
if ($svr == '/home6/dakproj1/public_html/condominios/.com/administrator.php') {
    echo   'background-image:url(images/'.$linea['imagenHeader'].'); background-repeat:no-repeat;';
} else {
   echo   'background-image:url(../images/'.$linea['imagenHeader'].'); background-repeat:no-repeat;';           
        }
```

i want to optimize this because this is a site i will have to replicate 4 or 5 times and on the server that path doesn't change automatically.....

how can i detect i am on the root or inside a subfolder..... thanks.

Comment: there is an error on the script this is what i have
if ($svr == '/home6/dakproj1/public_html/condominios/site1.com/administrator.php') {

Comment: Have you tried this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Answer (score 2):

use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
but its always better to create a config.php file and save it in your root directory. In the config file you define few parameters.

Call this config file in every page. Your config file can be similar to one below.

```
define('APP_NAME',"your_folder");  
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/'); 
define('SITE_NAME', 'http://localhost/');   
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].APP_NAME);
```

and check with these vars

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your root folder name";
    $filePath = dirname(__FILE__);
    if ($root == $filePath) {
       echo "root"; //  root folder
    } else {
       echo "Subfolders";  //subfolder or subdomain
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using predefined constants `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `__DIR__`:

```
function getcss(){
  if (__DIR__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']){
    include("PATH_TO_CSS/css1.php");
  }
  else {
    include("PATH_TO_CSS/css2.php");
  }
}
```

Then just call the `getcss()` function:

```
getcss();
```

Comment: it does not work it alwways include me css2.php no matter where its called

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dir=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($dir == "/"){
   include("css1.php");
}else{
   include("css2.php");
}
```

Comment: Hey there. Could you explain (or try to) why and how this solves the problem? From where I stand I'm under the impression your first condition won't ever be met... and btw, welcome to SO :)